# Как подключить #include "printBinary.h" в С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Дана программа с использованием поразрядных операторов.
Проблема в **printBinary.h**.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <conio.h> 
    #include <ctime>
    #include <printBinary.h> 

    using namespace std;
    //Вспомогательный макрос:
    #define PR(STR, EXPR) \ 
    cout << STR; printBinary(EXPR); cout << endl;

int main()
{
    unsigned int getval;
    unsigned char a,b;
    unsigned char c = 0x5A;//битовая маска
    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 255: ";
    cin >> getval; a = getval;
    PR("a in binary: ", a);
    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 255: ";
    cin >> getval; b = getval;
    PR("b in binary: ", b);
    PR("a | b = ", a | b);
    PR("a & b = ", a & b);
    PR("a ^ b = ", a ^ b);
    PR("~a = ", ~a);
    PR("~b = ", ~b);

    PR("c in binary: ", c);
    a |= c;
    PR("a |= c; a = ", a);
    b &= c;
    PR("b &= c; b = ", b);
    b ^= a;
    PR("b ^= a; b = ", b);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор сообщает:

> printBinary.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Это нестандартный header, который, судя по всему, написал кто-то сам. Спрашивать про него — это всё равно что спрашивать, где взять класс `MyClass`. Ответ — там же, где вы взяли ссылку на него.

Comment: VladD, понял, спасибо. Пример дан в книге, но проверить его в работе не смог.

Comment: Тогда посмотрите в книге на пару страниц назад, так где-то наверняка должен быть код.

Comment: Это функция из книги Thinking in C++ Брюса Экеля. Поищите в вебе printBinary.h и printBinary.cpp и вы найдёте, где выложен исходный код. Копирайт не позволяет оставить здесь ссылку.

Comment: Dmitri Chubarov, да, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Решение**](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/258414/undefined-reference-to-error)

Для того, чтобы компилятор не сообщал об отсутствии данного заголовка нужно добавить в директорию проекта два файла: ***printBinary.h*** и ***printBinary.cpp***. После чего программа будет работать исправно.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/187038)

Comment: Понял, исправлено.